# Bricked STM32 with Read Out Protection Level 1, can't disable it

Tags: stm32, protection

So I was testing the boot option bytes of my Nucleo32 STM32G431KB board and somehow my Nucleo board is in Read Out Protection level 1. STLink Utility is unable to revert it, I get the error "Read/Write protected zone for bank 1 can't be reduced".

[image]

These are the only lines of code I had in main():

```
//STCubeIDE autogenerated code...
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
HAL_FLASH_OB_Unlock();
FLASH->OPTR|=(1<<27);
SET_BIT(FLASH->CR, FLASH_CR_OPTSTRT);
HAL_FLASH_OB_Launch(); 
HAL_FLASH_Lock();
while(1)
{
}
//STCubeIDE autogenerated code...
```

I also tried to bypass the STLink and try if I could communicate directly to IC's bootloader using a FTDI driver and writing raw bytes to UART, because there is a command to revert the ROP, but I had no reply from the chip.

Comment: The readout protection feature would be pretty pointless if you could just reduce it like that in the ST-LINK utility. You'll probably have to erase the chip to clear the protection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've managed to recover the board, using STM32CubeProgrammer (not CubeIDE, this is a different program).

The only thing I had to do was changing RDP to 0xAA (no protection) and now I can reprogram the IC.

First install the program and click Connect to STLink, then:

[image]

Comment: Just a warning for readers of this answer: Do **not** choose `CC`. Doing so places uC in Level 2 protection, permanently disables debug and bricks the uC. You can not recover from Level 2 protection .